# wildfly 10 load balancer UT005041

Tags: java, server, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I was trying to configure wildly 10 for load balancing purpose. But after configuring it following error is coming on starting

> UT005041: Cannot send advertise message. Address: /224.0.1.105:0: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument"

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check which interface your modcluster configuration is using, for example:

```
<socket-binding name="modcluster" interface="private" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
```

If private, then probably, in your case, you need to set it for any address and also when you start your server, make sure to allow it through firewall then.

```
<interface name="private">
    <any-address/>
</interface>
```